# Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events

In my App component(simple one ), I have created a form with 3 input fields and 1 submit button. When the user fills the form and after clicking on submit button the form data is displayed on the page.

Now, my problem is that I am getting typescript error when accessing form elements node from  `event.target.elements`.

```
TypeError: Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

I tried to solve this problem by typecasting the `event.target` as HTMLInputElement but the error still persists.

```
function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { firstName, lastName, company } = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).elements;
    setFormData({
      firstName: firstName.value,
      lastName: lastName.value,
      company: company.value
    });
  }
```

Error message when I used the above code

```
TypeError: Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'.
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eventtargetelements-w0b7t?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to type the `event.target` in forms, you need to do it manually, see [forms and events TS cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events/).

```
interface FormData {
  firstName: { value: string };
  lastName: { value: string };
  company: { value: number[] };
}

function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const { firstName, lastName, company } = e.target as typeof e.target & FormData;
  setFormData({
    firstName: { value: firstName.value },
    lastName: { value: lastName.value },
    company: { value: company.value }
  });
}
```

[image: Edit Type e.target]

Comment: Can't I have elements through event.target.elements without typescript error?

Comment: You can try from `event.currentTaget.elements` but it wont be typed, you need to do it manually like in the example